# NavigationController nested in TabController animation bug

Tags: swift, xcode, navigationcontroller

I try my best to explain what is happening.

I have updated the XCode to **Version 10.1 (10B61)**

And the iOS on my iPhone and Simulator is v**12.1**

---

My app has a TabController with 5 tabs.

```
First: Posts
Fifth: Profile Posts
```

> These are embedded into a navigation controller (In case someone
>   clicks on the comments button)

So. I've noticed that if I run my app and I click the comments, it pushes that vc in a weird way to the screen, then clicking back just "bumps" back. Also slide back isn't working.

However, if I switch tabs first then everything works fine.

```
VIDEO:
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgS3j21L8Js

As you see in the video everything is fine after switching to **Profile Posts** + back .

**UPDATE 1:**

So if I start my app, switch to another Tab, then back to the original, it works fine.

Requested code:

```
func commentsButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        let touchPoint:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:self.tableView)
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            openDetails(indexPath: indexPath, shouldShowKeyboard: false)
        }
    }
func openDetails(indexPath: IndexPath, shouldShowKeyboard : Bool) {
        if (self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? WorldMessageCell) != nil {

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Additional", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") as! DetailsViewController

            vc.postId = PostIds.shared.nearby.ids[safe: indexPath.row]
            vc.shouldShowKeyboard = shouldShowKeyboard

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Solved the problem by forcing the TabController to switch between tabs..

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.selectedIndex = 1
        self.selectedIndex = 0

    }
```

But that's not how it should work..

**UPDATE 3:**

I have tested it, if I make the `navigation controller`->`vc` the initial vc (so no tab controller) everything works fine.

But as soon as the navigationcontroller is nested inside the tab, it happens.

I made a new project to test if this is a version specific bug but no, everything works fine there. So the issue must be with my app.

What could generate issue like that (in the video)?

Comment: Please share the code where you call both navigations.
My quick guess is that you're presenting them differently, but this seems quite obvious.

Comment: updated! The code is the same in both vcs

Answer (score 0):

Ohh.. I have found the problem & bug:

So if you have `navigation controllers` nested into a `tab controller` that calls it's `viewDidLoad()` function, then the navigation controller will have problems.

The code I had to remove totally:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // here i had some code ... /

    }
```

Now everything works..